# Sphinx sort mode, order by ascending, ignoring zeros

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I'm using Sphinx with SPH_SORT_EXTENDED.

```
$s->SetSortMode ( SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, 'webvalue asc' );
$s->SetRankingMode ( SPH_RANK_SPH04 );

$s->SetLimits($page, 8);
```

This is working fine, however my database contains rows where webvalue is 0.00 (webvalue is DECIMAL field type).

What I'd like to do is order by webvalue ascending, but essentially ignore zero values so they appear at the end of the results.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but couldn't you just use str_replace('.', '', $var); for each value, then sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already answered here, on the sphinxsearch forum: http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=12236